# the char pointer prints more garbage values if i give string in even length but working correctly for string with odd length...can anyone say why?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{

char string[100]="abbd"; 
int len=strlen(string);
char *left = &string[0];
char *right = &string[len-1];
char ans[10];
int k = 0;
while(left != right)
{
if(len%2 != 0)
{
    if(*left != *right)
    {
        ans[k++] = *left; 
    }
}
printf("%c",*left);
left++;
right--;
}
for(int i=k-1;i>=0;i--)
 printf("%c",ans[i]);
return 0;
}    "/* the code is for to make the string palindrome...
```

i know it is not fully correct but i need to know why more garbage value is printed for even length string alone */

Comment: On an even-length string `left` and `right` can pass each other. Change `while(left != right)` to `while(left < right)`.

Comment: thanks.....and also i have another doubt ..left doesn't equal to right its correct but how the program ended at last , instead it should keep on running right?? I am just curious to know

Comment: I wondered that; perhaps the system took control back after illegal memory access. Did the program actually terminate cleanly? There is more *undefined behaviour* with `ans[k++] = *left;` once `k > 9` so the question isn't really answerable.

Comment: oh...okk ok I got it...by the way thanks for your time...can you suggest any way to improve my knowledge in c :)

Comment: Practice, practice, practice; read the man page for every library function you use; and read the posts on this stack!

Answer (score 2):

Well, grab a pen and paper.

```
int len=strlen(string);
char *left = &string[0];
char *right = &string[len-1];
.
.
.
while(left != right) { ...
```

Suppose the string `"012345"`, where each element also represents its own address relative to the start of the array.

- at the beginning,

  ```
  left --> 0    right --> 5
  ```
- First iteration,

  ```
  left --> 1    right --> 4
  ```
- Second iteration,

  ```
  left --> 2    right --> 3
  ```
- Third iteration,

  ```
  left --> 3    right --> 2
  ```

Hence, as you can see, `left` was never equal to `right` when the string is of even length, the loop condition is never falsified, the pointers kept getting incrementing and decrementing, accessing beyond the range of your array and reading garbage.

Instead try:

```
while( left < right ) { ...
```